# Pull sem usar o Git Bash

Tags: git

Estou com problemas ao tentar fazer o `pull` diretamente do *Git Bash*, queria saber se tem outra forma de fazê-lo por outro caminho, como o *Git GUI* por exemplo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O **Git GUI** não tem o comando `pull`, porém um `git pull` não é nada mais que é um `git fetch` seguido de um `git merge`.

Você precisa ir em **Menu Remoto > Receber de > repo remoto** para fazer o `fecth` e depois ir no **Menu Mesclar > Mesclar localmente** para fazer o `merge`.

[Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22666828/no-pull-in-git-gui) tem uma pergunta no SOen falando sobre isso.

---

Se você estiver usando o [GitHub](https://github.com/) ou o [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/), há a possibilidade de usar o cliente desktop dos mesmos ([GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/) e [Atlassian SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/)) e fazer o `pull` por lá.

Comment: E como eu faria isso? Através do desktop?

Comment: No **Git GUI**.

Comment: Vlw a ajuda, mas eu reinstalei o **Git** e voltou a funcionar o `pull`